# Refresh editText in a thread

Tags: android, textview, real-time

I have made this code and i need to show in realtime some values on the screen, so, I was trying to do it like this, does anyone know how what is wrong?

```
public class Test extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView lastValue;
    int i = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        lastValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewID);
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() { 

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(i<90000) {
                    i++;
                    lastValue.setText(String.valueOf(i));

                }
        }});       t.start();

    }
}
```

Android Monitor:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
>   android.text.Layout.getLineCount()' on a null object reference
>                                                          at android.widget.TextView.onMeasure(TextView.java:7520)
>                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19917)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6139)
>                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1485)
>                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:775)
>                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:657)
>                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19917)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6139)
>                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
>                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19917)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6139)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:393)
>                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19917)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6139)
>                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19917)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6139)
>                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1485)
>                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:775)
>                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:657)
>                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19917)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6139)
>                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:729)
>                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19917)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2436)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2182)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1366)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6768)
>                                                          at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:923)
>                                                          at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:735)
>                                                          at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:667)
>                                                          at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:909)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:831)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is accessing a view from a thread. But the View is only available with UI Thread and hence null pointer exception is thrown. To achieve this you can try:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() { 
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(i<90000) {
            i++;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable {
                lastValue.setText(String.valueOf(i));
            });
        }
    }
});       
t.start();
```

`runOnUiThread` causes thread to run on UI Thread.

Comment: Good answer, try to add some explanation about why that error happens or something, dont post only code

Answer (score 2):

First point about your code,you cannot modify View objects from outside the UI thread.Therefore you should  use various handlers or  techniques to accomplish it ,Like as @Embydextrous answers

second point ,if your code fails for this reason which is UI thread, logchat  will be like this

```
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6566)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:911)
```

But your logchat is very different.Problem will be something else,Is it all logs ? probably errors reason is your layout ,check it

Answer (score 0):

In the development of Android, all displayed in the UI interface controls are in a separate thread UI-Thread (or called MainThread); when you want to refresh the interface in the other thread, must jump to UIThread, you can use Handler to achieve this operation.

```
public class Test extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int REFRESH_LASTVALUE=0;
private Handler handler=new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what){
            case REFRESH_LASTVALUE:
                lastValue.setText((String)msg.obj);
                break;
        }
    }
};
TextView lastValue;
int i = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    lastValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewID);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(i<90000) {
                i++;
                Message message=new Message();
                message.what=REFRESH_LASTVALUE;
                message.obj=String.valueOf(i);
            }
        }}).start();

}
```

}

or you can use runOnUiThread,that is also achieved through Handler, Message, and so forth.